# Use the isomorphism theorem to determine the group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Use the isomorphism theorem to determine the group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Here $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant not equal to $0$, and $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the group of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$. In the first part of the problem, I proved that $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$. Now it wants me to use the isomorphism theorem. I tried using
$$|GL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{R})|=|GL_2(\mathbb{R})|/|SL_2(\mathbb{R})|,$$

but since both groups have infinite order, I don't think I can use this here.

Comment: Hint: Can you find a group $G$ and a homomorphism $h : \mathsf{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \to G$ so that $\text{ker}(h) = \mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$? As a more detailed hint, you've already recognized the defining property of $\mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is that the determinant is $1$...

Comment: Since $\det:GL_2(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ is surjective then $GL_2(\mathbb R)/SL_2(\mathbb R)\cong\mathbb R\smallsetminus\{0\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define  $f:GL_2(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^*$ such that

> $$\underbrace{f(M)=\det(M)}_{\text{Onto}}$$

Let  $M_1, M_2 \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}^*) $ then

$f(M_1 M_2)=\det(M_1 M_2)=\det(M_1)\det(M_2)=f(M_1)(M_2)$

Hence $f$ is homomorphism for $\ker(f)=\{M: M\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})\text{ such that }\det(M)=1\}=SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

From first theorem in isomorphism

$GL_2(\mathbb{R})/SL_2(\mathbb{R})\approx \mathbb{R}^*$